# Where and when to transform data with Azure data factory Data Flow activity?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm trying to transform data on the cloud with Azure Data Factory Data Flow Activity, previously I have created a pipeline that contains copy activity and some other(it takes lists of table names from SQL server and passed it as a parameter to another activity that does the actual copy), and I learned to created data flow activity to transform data and put it on another activity, when do I need to trigger that data flow activity.

Comment: Hi Saranraj. Put that activity right after some data preparation (such a copy, etc) and then do all transformations/business logic you require. So, in other words, Data Flow is just another activity in your ADF Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kamil said, you can add a data flow like any other activity. Just look for it in the Acitivities menu as shown below, add dependencies from or to another activities, select the data flow you want to execute and you are good to go!

[image: Adding a data flow to a pipeline]

Hope this helped!